# Using mclapply, foreach, or something else in [r] to operate on an object in parallel?

Tags: r, memory, foreach, parallel-processing, fork

Is there a way to operate on an object in `R` in parallel? I understand that `mclapply` in `parallel` fork processes and copy the workspace contents to each process. I would instead like instead to have my cores perform independent jobs on an object, without having to split and combine results. A use case would be changing all `numeric` columns in a data.frame to `factor` columns in parallel. Another use case would be binning factors in a data.frame that have a large number of levels. The main reasons I am trying to do this are 1) to avoid running out of memory and 2) to increase speed.

Below, object `b` is the result of splitting columns in the data.frame `a` and then combining them after applying `factor`. Instead, I would like to operate directly on the object `a`. In serial, I am able to convert the columns in `a` to `factor` types as a side-effect of the `foreach...%do%` loop. In parallel, I am unable to convert the columns of `a` to `factor` types as a side effect, because (as I understand it) inside the `foreach...%dopar%`, `a` refers to an object that is local to each spawned process.

Is there a package in `R` that will let me do this?

```
a <- data.frame(b=c(1,1,2,2), c=c(2,2,3,3))
str(a)

> str(a)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ b: num  1 1 2 2
 $ c: num  2 2 3 3

#serial
b <-
  foreach (i = iter(1:ncol(a)), .combine = data.frame) %do% {
    a[,i] <- factor(a[,i])
  }
str(a)
str(b)

> str(a)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ b: Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 2 2
 $ c: Factor w/ 2 levels "2","3": 1 1 2 2
> str(b)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ result.1: Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 2 2
 $ result.2: Factor w/ 2 levels "2","3": 1 1 2 2

#parallel
a <- data.frame(b=c(1,1,2,2), c=c(2,2,3,3))
b <-
  foreach (i = iter(1:ncol(a)), .combine = data.frame) %dopar% {
    a[,i] <- factor(a[,i])
  }
str(a)
str(b)

> str(a)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ b: num  1 1 2 2
 $ c: num  2 2 3 3
> str(b)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ result.1: Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 2 2
 $ result.2: Factor w/ 2 levels "2","3": 1 1 2 2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you have to be aware that R is (generally) `call by value`, so whatever you do you'll always end up with temporary copies of your data frame. That goes for the normal versions of the apply family as well. Once you change something inside the function, the object is copied first.

This said, `mclapply` does NOT copy the complete workspace contents to the child processes. As far as I understood, the processes share the same memory content and only copy the content once a modification is made to it. Which comes down more or less to what R does anyway.

If you still don't trust this, you could use the cluster approach and try `parLapply` and friends from the `parallel` package. This is not based on forking, but on node clusters. You can see your cores as nodes here. In this case, you have to explicitly export the variables from the workspace you need for the calculations using `clusterExport()`. I am not sure about this, but I suspect that this does create a copy. For the rest, `parLapply` copies only the elements it works on to the different clusters. So again, this is rather the same as what `lapply` does by default.

Working with your data frame `a`, you coul do eg :

```
> require(parallel)
> cl <- makeCluster(2)
> b <- parLapply(cl,a,as.factor)
> str(as.data.frame(b))
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ b: Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 2 2
 $ c: Factor w/ 2 levels "2","3": 1 1 2 2
> stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Regarding copying the workspace, I might have misinterpreted page 2 of http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/doc/parallel.pdf. I also have been running into an issue when using `mclapply` on a 3GB data.frame of each spawned process showing ~3GB of memory consumption in UNIX's `top`. (For code like: `mclapply(chunkify(dat, chunks = mc.cores), mc.cores = mc.cores, FUN = function(x) someFunction(x))` where `chunkify` returns a list of `chunks` sub-data.frames of `dat` -- I thought child processes would only use ~3GB/mc.cores of memory).

Comment: @lockedoff Well, the sentence you should look at is : "However, the copy will (in any reasonable OS) share memory pages with the master until modied so forking is very fast." It depends on your OS instead of your R version, and on the Debian we run here, I didn't experience this. Also keep in mind that manipulation might result in more than one copy of your data in the memory. I had situations where manipulating a dataframe inflated the used memory to five times the original size. This got better though in later versions of R, but is also dependent on how you code.

Comment: I noticed a huge difference in total memory consumption when testing parLapply and mclapply yesterday in Ubuntu - thanks. I might post a separate question after I investigate further. As for my original question, I understand that R uses call-by-value, but in my code I passed only indices to `foreach` and tried to modify an object, `a`, outside of its scope. In the case of %do% (serial), it worked (as it would in a `for` loop), and in the case of %dopar% (parallel), it failed. I am still looking for a way to do operations on a object in parallel without copying, applying, collecting..

Comment: I found that using `foreach` with a `data.table` where I split by some key value and just pass the chunks out was very efficient.  I believe the `data.table` is then passed out by reference.  Very much depends on the use case but it helped me deal with the memory issue